# Get sum of integers with old numbers 1 + (1 + 2) + (1 + 2 + 3) + ... + (1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n)

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to reach this :

```
1 + (1 + 2) + (1 + 2 + 3) + ... + (1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n)
```

I'm already getting this result:-

```
(1 + 2) + (2 + 3)
```

with this code :

```
int n = 8;
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++){
     int j = i + 1;
     System.out.print("(" + i + " + " +  j + ")");
}
```

How can I achieve the top result ?

Comment: Hint: you probably need 2 loops

Comment: @aoiee i just need to solve it with loops only.

Comment: are you sure it's not`1 + (1 + 2) + (1 + 2 + 3) + ... + (1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n)` ?

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger well it's seems a common one, yea i need that.

Comment: As already said, two simple loops, one that always sums up from `1` to `n`, and one outer loop that increases `n`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two loops like this :

```
int n = 8;

String del;
String del2 = "";

for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    System.out.print(del2 + "(");
    del = "";
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
        System.out.print(del + j);
        del = " + ";
    }
    System.out.print(")");
    del2 = " + ";
}
```

#### code demo

Comment: @YCF_L, I meant both for loops should be `<=` instead of `<`

Comment: sry that was a missing click.

Answer (score 1):

Move the declaration of `j` before the loop and initialize it with `0`, then just add the current `i` to `j`.

> That would solve what?  – AKSW

This would calculate the sum of the equation.

To print the equation you also need one loop only:

```
int n = 8;
StringBuilder equation = new StringBuilder("1");
StringBuilder equationGroup = new StringBuilder("1");

for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
    equationGroup.append(" + ");
    equationGroup.append(i);
    equation.append(" + (");
    equation.append(equationGroup.toString());
    equation.append(")");
}
System.out.println(equation.toString());
```

Comment: That would solve what? How would that work without a second loop?

Comment: @AKSW that probably is meant to just solve the mathematical formula, not building the string

Answer (score 1):

Well, thanks @YCF_L for your answer it's the correct one, but this complete one after edit, i posted it in case some one need the complete solution:

```
    int n = 8;
    String del;
    String delPlus = "";
    String rightPract = "", leftPract = "";
    for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
        System.out.print(delPlus + rightPract);
        del = "";
        for (int j = 1; j < i; j++) {
            System.out.print(del + j);
            del = " + ";
        }
        System.out.print(leftPract);
        delPlus = " + ";
        rightPract = "(";
        leftPract = ")";
    }
```

Now the result is :-

```
1 + (1 + 2) + (1 + 2 + 3) + (1 + 2 + 3 + 4) + (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5) + (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you take the recursion approach you have to think of it as a **recursion inside another recursion**. `add(i,n)` generates 1 and (1+2) and (1+2+3) up to (1+2+3...n). then the `sum(i,n)` recursively sum them together

```
public static int add(int i, int n){
    if(i == n){
        return n;
    }
    return i + add(i+1,n);
}

public static int sum(int i, int n){
    if(i == n){
        return add(0,n);
    }
    return add(0, i) + sum(i+1,n);
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    int n = 8;
    System.out.print(sum(0, n));
}
```